# Extract value from title and add to files

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files. The files all have a similar name 'Antwerp_listings_201903', 'Antwerp_listings_201904', ..... (with different dates).

I would like to add an extra column to the csv files with the date from the title (year and month).

My goals is to have 1 CSV file but having the date (from the files names) in one extra column, so i can filter on date.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# getting all csv file names
files =  glob.glob("path/to/csv/files/*.csv")

# extracting year and date from title
dates = []
for file_name in files:
    date = file_name.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
    year, month = date[0:4], date[4:]
    dates.append((year+"/"+month)) # change this according to your format

year_and_date = pd.Series(dates)
# adding column in each file
for file_name in files:
    csv_file = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    csv_file["year_and_month"] = year_and_date
    csv_file.to_csv(file_name, index=False)

# creating a new csv file with year and date column only
year_and_date.to_csv("year_and_date.csv", header=['year_and_date'], index=False)
```